# How can I handle many concurrent connections in fastapi websocket endpoint?

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

Hello FastAPI experts,
A few months ago, I built an hobby project which serves trading information using websocket.
But I got stuck with concurrent clients connection. If I set env variable as `WEB_CONCURRENCY=4`, and open 4 browsers (4 concurrent web client connections), no more clients can connect to the server.
I believe that thousands of concurrent connection is possible depending on server hardware capability.
Full code exists here, which is not bloated:
https://github.com/dockerlead/iqoption-trading-server
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any update on this? Any further experiment, poc etc

Comment: No, not yet. Help needed.